# How can I programmatically end a Chat on Pepper?

Tags: chatbot, pepper

I have a simple chatbot with the below topic file and would like to end the chat (and stop Pepper from listening) when the user says a key phrase (e.g. "bye).

```
u: (hello) hi

u: (my name is _*) nice to meet you $1

u: (bye) goodbye %endChat
```

However i haven't found any action (smth like chat.end()) and the docs state "If you want to stop the chat when a qiChatbot is stopped you must track the state of the QiChatbot and manually stop the chat when the QiChatbot ends."

Any idea how / what event to listen on to do this?
I'm using the Android / Java based version of Pepper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [^endDiscuss](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/qichat/qichat_syntax.html#enddiscuss) keyword in QiChat to end the current chat.

In QiChat:

```
u: (hello) hi
u: (my name is _*) nice to meet you $1
u: (bye) goodbye ^endDiscuss(endReason)
```

Then listen for the QiChatbot ended event like [this](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/reference/qichatbot.html#ending-chat) in your app and, when it is triggered, close the chat. Like the docs say, you can pass an ending reason from the QiChat if you have multiple ending conditions and want to do different things.

In Java:

```java
// Create a QiChatbot
final QiChatbot qichatbot = QiChatbotBuilder.with(qiContext)
                                            .withTopic(topic)
                                            .build();

// Create a Chat
final Chat chat = ChatBuilder.with(qiContext)
                             .withChatbot(qichatbot)
                             .build();

// Execute the chat asynchronously
final Future<Void> fchat = chat.async().run();

// Stop the chat when the qichatbot is done
qichatbot.addOnEndedListener(endReason -> {
    Log.i(TAG, "qichatbot end reason = " + endReason);
    fchat.requestCancellation();
});
```

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to pause the chatbot rather than end it, and then resume from where it left off? 

E.g. if, based on the human user input, Pepper calls an API, then speaks out the result (dynamically, not pre-scripted), then resumes to the next user rule?

u: (weather) In which city %getWeather
u: (pet) do you have a pet?

The getWeather would fetch the weather via APIs, then launch a Say, then pass back to the chatbot?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [^execute](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/qichat/qichat_syntax.html#execute) tag to call an externally defined function then return to the chatbot with the response. There's an example [here](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/reference/baseQiChatExecutor.html#baseqichatexecutor). I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but getting "The robot cannot hear while it is talking" if i try to launch a Say in the function, unless I terminate the chat. What I'd like to do is pause the chat, run the external function and launch a Say action, then return to the chat and resume the conversation. Thanks again for your helpo

Comment: Instead of trying to launch the Say in your external function, have a variable in your qiChat file, set that variable in your external function using the [QiChatVariable](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/reference/qichatvariable.html#qichatvariable) class, then access that variable for the response in QiChat. Something like: `u:(weather) Let me think. ^execute(myExecutor,weather) The weather is $weather`

Comment: Hi Dominic, what you say makes perfect sense, however i just can't seem to find any way to get the results back for the life of me. 
To clarify - i'm capturing the user command via the $city parameter in the topic file, I then address that in my Activity by calling chatbot.variable("city"), i launch a QiChatExecutor, i run call the weather API under the runWith() function, but how do i pass the result back from the Executor object to the chatbot so the robot can speak out the result? Many thanks

Comment: To return the value. Have a `$weather` variable QiChat. Then in Java, `QiChatVariable weather = qiChatbot.variable("weather");` Then later: `weather.setValue("sunny");`. Back in QiChat: `The weather is $weather` = "The weather is sunny". There's a tutorial [here](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/tuto/qichatvariable_tutorial.html#qichatvariable-tutorial)

Comment: after few days of sweating i got it to work - tremendous help, @Dominic D, many thanks! :-)